# theming jquery ui with multiselect listboxes

Tags: jquery-ui, listbox, theming

it doesn't seem that jquery ui themes does anything to multiselect listboxes.  does anyone know the reason why or have any way of having multiselect listboxes match the theme of other ui elements when using jquery ui theming css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [jQuery UI Multiselect](http://www.quasipartikel.at/multiselect/) plugin. It is styleable via [Themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).

Comment: @Raul Agrait - do you know if there is any programatic way to add and remove items once you use the jquery ui multiselect plugin

Answer (score 0):

I Like Eric Hynds jQuery UI Multiselect widget which supports all UI Themeroller styles as well as supporting content refresh.  Fully customizable.

https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget